# Cypress. Why is my route alias not matching?

Tags: cypress

My POST request to ocr/receipt is never matched. I've...

- created a route, matching **/ocr/**, specifying POST, and given it an alias.
- called `wait()` with a long timeout.

I can watch the request complete in the network pane while the wait spinner turns happily in the test pane. Why is Cypress not matching this route?

```
beforeEach(function () {
    cy.route('POST','**/ocr/**').as('ocr');
});
it('Création frais depuis le bouton « appareil photo »', function () {
    cy.get('.in-progress').first().click()
    cy.wait('@ocr', {'timeout':15000});
    cy.get('#grpChoices > :nth-child(1)').click();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well who would have guessed. **Method is case sensitive, and it only works in *lower case***. So...

```
route('post','**/ocr/**').as('ocr')
```

fixed it.
[The doc won't help you](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Arguments).

The other recurring reason for routes not triggering is if your app uses the fetch api. Fetch is not compatible with cypress.

Comment: I have the same issue, however a lowercase `'post'` does not fix it.

Comment: _update_: My issue is related to `fetch()` not being supported: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/95

Comment: FYI, I use cypress at work and all of our routes work correctly and have uppercase HTTP methods. We use axios for XHR. Not sure if that is why, but it works.

Comment: Yup. I've seen UPPERCASE working more recently too. The post is more than a year old but hand on my heart it was true at the time !

Comment: I have a PUT route that is identical to my GET route. The PUT route works just fine lowercase, and the GET request is not matching. Oof.

Comment: method in any case is supported now: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1536

Answer (score 0):

In my case I defined the same alias in cy.route().as('acme') and cy.request().as('acme'). Even though the Cypress docs points out that cy.wait does not [support requests](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Yields) it does not point out that aliases should be unique. Rename or removing cy.request.as('foo') solves this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure for all requests, you have a response.